# What is the `data bit width of memory` in 64-bits architecture(say `RISCV64`)?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture, riscv

For 32-bits architecture, everything is clear, but I'm a little confused about 64-bits architecture. What is the `data bus width(not address bus width) of memory` in general? I know that the main memory on PC is composed of multiple DRAM chips then multiple 8-bits form the accessing data bit width. But just simplify it into a big whole memory(its depth is the range of memory address bus, and the width is the data bus width).

1. Suppose the width is `64-bits` as same as general registers. But the `instruction length` and the `instruction register` width are both 32, so the high 32-bits need to be disgarded. It seems to be a bit of wasting storage.
2. Suppose the width is `32-bits`. Nothing to say about fetching instrcutions. But for some instructions like `ld` and `sd`, two read operations are required for the memory itself. This reduces the efficiency.

So, what is the common trade-off or implementation?

`NOTE:` Let's take RV64 as examples. I don't know if there are differences when using the MMU and the virtual addresses. If yes, please explain that.

Thanks a lot!

I'm learning RISCV and writing a simulator, and preparing to coding RTL. This question came to my mind and I want to know the industrial practices.

Comment: How would it be "wasting storage"?  Are you picturing that instructions would get zero-extended to 64-bit instead of packed normally?  No, a design without cache would either keep the whole 64-bit chunk in a buffer and decode the high half next (if the first wasn't a jump), or would fetch each 64-bit chunk twice, once when it wanted the low 32 bits, again when it wanted the high 64 bits.  (RV64 supports data load/store of 8, 16, 32, and 64-bit widths, so the CPU needs to be able to take the part of the bus-width chunk it wants.)

Comment: Also keep in mind that some 32-bit CPUs, like P5 Pentium, have 64-bit external data busses, so they can fill their cache faster.  (And for 64-bit atomic load/store even on uncacheable data, e.g. using the integrated FPU).

Comment: The data bus size is an implementation detail, not an instruction set architecture issue.  A processor can have a data bus width that is smaller, the same, or larger than the register or instruction widths.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying the zero-extended situations. I think the 32-bits space is wasted because this space can be used to store something else(maybe just becase I'm a perfectionist :) ). So if the data bus width of memory is implementation-defined and it is not equal to instrcution length, there must be redundant operations(like `case 2` I said)? But actually can this performance loss be covered by using cache or some other technologies because of the difference of access speed. Besides, does it make more sense if we know which is more likely to use 32 or 64 bits datas in software apps?@PeterCordes

Comment: RISCV has 16-bit and 32-bit instructions.  There is no zero extension of instructions, even on RV64.

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood Peter Cordes's first comment. Thanks!